# Trigger para ligar vários registros

Tags: mysql, trigger

Possuo 3 tabelas:

```
Usuarios (id, nome)
Desafios (id, descricao) 
Usuarios_tem_desafios (id_usuario, id_desafio, status)
```

O objetivo é, ao adicionar um novo usuário, preencher a tabela `Usuarios_tem_desafios` com a ligação entre o usuário adicionado e os desafios cadastrados.

Comment: No teu caso, acho melhor utilizar [Procedures](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html) ou `Functions`

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly você acha que essa é uma regra complexa pra um trigger?

Comment: Não inicialmente, mas o ponto é que isso me parece estar relacionado a negócio e não infraestrutura (eu sou velha guarda nesse sentido, uso *triggers* para necessidades ortogonais como logs, atualização de datas, etc). Hoje a regra é inserir todos os desafios para todos os novos usuários, amanhã a regra pode ter um filtro complicado conforme as características de cadastro do usuário, depois a *feature* pode evoluir para usar várias tabelas, etc. Eu acredito que a melhor política é tentar manter regras de negócio em uma única camada.

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly pra esse caso não. Entendi seu conselho e até acataria se eu soubesse que poderia tornar-se mais complexo. Mas isso é só para poupar trabalho de não estar inserindo um a um, pois eu não irei criar uma página para o usuário se cadastrar. Eu mesmo cadastrarei direto no banco, porque é só para fins acadêmicos.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode implementar um *trigger* `AFTER INSERT` em `Usuarios`. A ideia é usar o comando [`INSERT ... SELECT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html) para selecionar todos os desafios e inserir entradas correspondentes em `Usuarios_tem_desafios`:

```sql
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER novos_desafios AFTER INSERT ON Usuarios 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO Usuarios_tem_desafios
       (id_usuario, id_desafio, status)
           SELECT NEW.id, id, 'novo' 
           FROM Desafios;
END;//

DELIMITER ;
```

**Veja funcionando no [Paiza.io](https://paiza.io/projects/BcDphPYlH0Sh0V55_pcHkA)**

---

Dito isso, enquanto o OP deixou claro nos comentários que esse é um projeto acadêmico, aconselho evitar ao máximo lidar com regras de negócio em *triggers*. Esse pequeno exemplo está com certeza lidando com regras de negócio:

1. Ao inserir um usuário ele deve ser associado a novos desafios.
2. Um desafio associado a um usuário deve começar no status "novo" (chute meu)

O problema é que em Software real as regras de negócio podem evoluir com o tempo, devido a isso, é sempre uma boa ideia manter o código centralizado em uma camada de fácil manutenção. *Triggers* são o oposto disso, o código acaba espalhado e a manutenção pode rapidamente se tornar uma dor de cabeça.

Não há nada de errado em usar *triggers* para lidar com [Cross-cutting concerns](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-cutting_concern), por exemplo, para manter registros de auditoria, etc. Mas minha recomendação é sempre tentar minimizar o uso de *triggers*.

Comment: Beleza, cara. Obrigado pela dica!

Comment: Oi Marcelo, sem problemas. Se seu problema foi resolvido não se esqueça por favor de aceitar a resposta em questão (bem como votar positivamente em respostas úteis).

Answer (score 0):

atendendo a sua solicitação reescrevi, devido as alterações feitas preferir postar como outra resposta. Como o `TRIGGER` não aceita parâmetro, para adicionar um usuário direto na partida com um desafio já proposto, teríamos que possuir a id do desafio, devido a essa deficiência foi necessário criar um campo na tabela de usuários chamado `DesafioAtual` do tipo `INT` que por padrão recebe **1** que refere-se ao primeiro desafio da Tabela de Desafio. Com isso o usuário terá por padrão seu primeiro desafio assim que for incluso.

Após essa inclusão o TRIGGER entra em ação Executando um INSERT em Partidas;
Da forma como pensei, assim que o usuario completar um determinado desafio e partir paro o proximo, você usa um UPDATE para alterar o campo DesafioAtual e receber o numero do novo desafio.
Agora com o primeiro modelo do TRIGGER, use como exemplo para cria um novo só que do tipo `AFTER UPDATE`. Dentro dele repeta a query `INSERT INTO Partidas(UsuarioID, DesafioID) VALUES(NEW.ID, NEW.DesafioAtual);` e pronto!

Segue Imgem abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como não foi o esperado e atendendo ao ultimo comentário usei o While para inserção dos 15 registros a cada usuário inserido.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Espero que possa ter resolvido.

Comment: Cara, me diz se é possível fazer assim: dentro do gatilho, criar uma variável que recebe a quantidade de desafios cadastrados. Fazer um laço sobre essa quantidade e, dentro do laço, fazer a inserção do id do usuário e o id do desafio (que no caso será o contador do laço). Entendeu?

Comment: é possível usar laço sim dentro do TRIGGER, só que o disparo ira acontece antes ou depois de um INSERT, DELETE e UPDATE. Tem com obter as colunas da tabela, usando NEW ou OLD. Vamos ver se entendi: a cada usuário inserido, podemos usar o loop no TRIGGER para adicionar todos os desafios disponível  para um usuário. É isso?

Comment: Isso. Eu tenho 15 desafios pré-cadastrados. Quando eu adicionar um novo usuário, o trigger deve inserir 15 registros na tabela Usuarios_tem_desafios, onde cada registro é o id do usuário inserido e o id de cada um dos 15 desafios.

Comment: @MarceloAugusto, vê se com essa edição é possível resolver o problema agora.